# ImmutableDictionary TryAdd

Tags: c#

`ImmutableDictionary` has a `TryAdd` method it gets from `System.Collections.Generic.CollectionExtensions` (which for some reason I can't find in DotNetPeek)

So this compiles:

```
ImmutableDictionary<int, int> d = ImmutableDictionary<int, int>.Empty;
bool b = d.TryAdd(1, 1);
```

However I don't understand what it does ? shouldn't it return a new ImmutableDictionary ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[ImmutableDictionary.Add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn466983(v=vs.111).aspx) does indeed return a new ImmutableDictionary with the value. The extension method you're referring to looks like it comes [from here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Collections/src/System/Collections/Generic/CollectionExtensions.cs).

I wouldn't advise using this extension method with an Immutable dictionary, as while this will compile, you will get a `NotSupportedException` at run-time.

Having looked a little further, [according to this,](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Collections.Immutable/src/System/Collections/Immutable/ImmutableDictionary_2.cs) the explicit interface implementation for `IDictionary<T,TR>.Add` will simply throw `NotSupportedException`, which seems appropriate.

[From the source,](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Collections.Immutable/src/System/Collections/Immutable/ImmutableDictionary_2.cs)

```
void IDictionary<TKey, TValue>.Add(TKey key, TValue value)   
{
    throw new NotSupportedException();
}
```

Comment: way better answer than mine.

Comment: @kofifus its not really a bug. its just a limit of interfaces. if you cast the immutable dictionary, as noted it will throw.

Comment: having a method that does nothing is to me buggy behavior and run time checks are just not good enough, ImmutableDictionary should not inherit CollectionExtensions

Comment: @kofifus it doesn't. it really should have only implemented `IReadOnlyDictionary` instead.

Answer (score 2):

`TryAdd` likely binds to `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` which `ImmutableDictionary<TKey, TValue>` implements. Likely it doesn't have any knowlege of a `ImmutableDictionary` and follows the `Try...` pattern resulting in a `bool` value.